# Change Jenkins build number

Tags: jenkins

I have a build that builds one two node at once and deploys the code from each node to the corresponding servers. Jenkins runs one build for each node, creating two builds for every time I press run. Is there a way to change the build numbering system to go from `#33`, `#34`, `#35`, `#36` to `#33 - a`, `#33 - b`, `#34 - a`, `#34 - b`?

This is what it currently looks like

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do would break the build number, because Jenkins would not know how to increment `33-a` to `34-a`.

Your pipeline is most likely incorrectly developed.
In Jenkins you can have a **single** build which runs in parallel across **multiple nodes** in which case you'd have a single build number.

This is called [`matrix`](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/) job. You can also just use a `parallel stages` -- it runs the `stage` blocks in parallel across multiple nodes.

Here's an example of a parallel stage configuration:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('OS') {
            parallel {
                stage('linux') {
                    agent {
                        label 'linux'
                    }
                    steps {
                        // Do my build.
                    }
                }
                stage('windows') {
                    agent {
                        label 'windows'
                    }
                    steps {
                        // Do my build.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This then shows up as this

[image]

And it will run your build in parallel on a windows and a linux agent.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a Jenkins super user and most configuration I have done is through the UI. I see the option for `Multi-configuration project` but I do not know where to place the configuration you provided. would that go inside a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: You need to use the `pipeline` option and there you can put the pipeline code from above. :)